# How-to change an isolated scope attribute of AngularJS directive from an external directive callback method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-scope

I need your help ! :)

I'm quite new to AngularJS (v1.2) development, and I'm playing with directives.

## The problem

I pass a parent ctrl model attr to my directive, that has its inner model in its isolated scope. The 2-ways data binding works fine between the parent ctrl attr and the directive's scope attr.

My problem is then that I want to update the directive's model attr from an external callback function of my parent ctrl, WITHOUT knowing which is the parent ctrl attribute to update...

This is because an event from my directive (like add an element in a list) must perform an async call to a REST WS to save the new element in the back-end, and update the angularJS associated model with the 'fresh' data received in the response (for example my data with an ID after it has been saved in the database...)

## Reproduce it

I don't know if this is clear, it should be hard to understand "as is", so I made a JSFiddle to demonstrate this with a very basic example : [TEST IT HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5yrw484z/5/).

If you type something in the "INTERNAL Callback" input text, you will call a method in the directive's scope. The model received from the async call (for example "{id:100, name:'JSFiddle'}") will be set to the directive's inner model, and reflected to the parent's scope model as well. FINE !

BUT if you type something in the "EXTERNAL Callback" input text, you will call a method in the parent's controller scope, with a 'model' method attribute that is the directive's scope attribute. The model received from the async call (for example "{id:100, name:'JSFiddle'}") will be set to the callback method model, and NOT reflected to the parent's scope model NOR the directive's model...

The only way I've found is to pass the directive's scope as the external callback attribute, and then update the desired attribute in this scope. That will work, but this is strange and awful in my opinion to pass the whole directive's scope to the callback method... You can [see it in action HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vncaqh20/2/).

Of course, you can tell me that I just have to update my parent controller model in my external callback method, but as I can use MANY directives in the same view/controller, used in "ng-repeat" items, using the same callback method, I can't know which parent ctrl scope attribute I should update... [See this case HERE.](http://jsfiddle.net/uutmdec3/1/)

Any ideas ?

## The example code

#### HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h1>Parent Ctrl</h1>
  <p>ctrlModel.id = {{ctrlModel.id}}</p>
  <p>ctrlModel.name = {{ctrlModel.name}}</p>
  <hr/>
  <h1>Directive</h1>
  <my-directive my-model="ctrlModel" on-change="ctrlOnChange(model)"></my-directive>
</div>
```

#### JAVASCRIPT:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, $log) {
    $scope.ctrlModel = {id:0, name:'StackOverflow'};

    $scope.ctrlOnChange = function(paramModel){
        $log.info('MyCtrl.ctrlOnChange / paramModel BEFORE = ' + JSON.stringify(paramModel));
      // Async call to save the model remotely and get it with an ID for example
      /*
      $http.post('/api/save-this-model-please', model)
        .then(function(response){
            model = response.data;
          // Here my LOCAL METHOD model 'paramModel' will be updated with saved data, including an ID !== 0
          // 'ctrlModel' in PARENT scope of 'MyCtrl' AND DIRECTIVE model 'scope.directiveModel' are not synced with these "fresh" data...
        });
      */
      paramModel = {id:100, name:'JSFiddle'};
      $log.info('MyCtrl.ctrlOnChange / paramModel AFTER = ' + JSON.stringify(paramModel));
    };
}

myApp.directive('myDirective', function ($log) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div><p>directiveModel.id = {{directiveModel.id}}</p><p>directiveModel.name = {{directiveModel.name}}</p><p>INTERNAL Callback : <input ng-model="directiveModel.name" ng-change="onChangeInternalCallback()"></p><p>EXTERNAL Callback : <input ng-model="directiveModel.name" ng-change="onChangeExternalCallback({model:directiveModel})"></p></div>',
    replace: true,
    transclude: false,

    scope: {
      directiveModel: '=myModel',
      onChangeExternalCallback: '&onChange'
    },

    link: function (scope) { // , element, attrs

    scope.onChangeInternalCallback = function(){
        $log.info('myDirective.onChangeInternalCallback / directiveModel BEFORE = ' + JSON.stringify(scope.directiveModel));
      // Async call to save the model remotely and get it with an ID for example
      /*
      $http.post('/api/save-this-model-please', scope.directiveModel)
        .then(function(response){
            scope.directiveModel = response.data;
          // Here my DIRECTIVE model 'scope.directiveModel' will be updated with saved data, including an ID !== 0
          // With 2-ways data binding, 'ctrlModel' in PARENT scope of 'MyCtrl' is ALSO synced with these "fresh" data...
        });
      */
      scope.directiveModel = {id:100, name:'JSFiddle'};
      $log.info('myDirective.onChangeInternalCallback / directiveModel AFTER = ' + JSON.stringify(scope.directiveModel));
    };

    }

  };
});
```

Comment: Have you considered using events (i.e. $rootsScope.emit and $rootScope.on) in order to broadcast state change?